# How to get the response data to use outside the JsonObjectRequest function

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have written a small program using JsonObjectRequest to get the data from an API, but I've got the result but I can't use it outside the function. Can anyone help me about it? I've got stuck here for 5 days already. When I want to use response data outside of this, it always show the token is null.

Here's my code.

```
RequestQueue requestQueue1=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonObjectRequest objectRequest1=new JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET,
        urlToken,
        null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                parseJson(response);

                try {
                    token=response;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }
);
requestQueue1.add(objectRequest1);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: if you want to call makeApiCall function every time you get response from this volley request you can just call that function after token = response part then the function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Using interface call back could be a solution: Code looks like :

```
interface TokenCallback {
void onTokenReceived(String token);
void onDataReceived(String responseData);
}
    private void makeApiCall(String url,String token,Boolean isGetRequest,TokenCallback tokenCallback){
    RequestQueue requestQueue1=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    // put if else to adjust GET or POST request
    if (isGetRequest){
        // prepare Get request
    }else {
        // Prepare post request
    }
    JsonObjectRequest objectRequest1=new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            token,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    parseJson(response);

                    try {
                        // Parse token here
                        if (response.has("token")){
                            tokenCallback.onTokenReceived(token);
                        }else {
                            tokenCallback.onDataReceived(response.toString());
                        }
                        
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue1.add(objectRequest1);
}
```

Call above method where you are starting API call like below:

```
            makeApiCall("https://your.api.url",null,true,new TokenCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onTokenReceived(String token) {
                    if(!token.isEmpty()){
                        // use token
                        makeApiCall("https://your.api.url",token,false,new TokenCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTokenReceived(String token) { }

                            @Override
                            public void onDataReceived(String responseData) {
                                // Parse your json response data here......
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDataReceived(String responseData) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Your help is worked, but I need to use this token to request to the same API for another function. And I put the other request in the makeApiCall, and the request is error. In this case, what should I do?

Comment: That means you want to call makeApiCall() method multiple times and each time it receives different respone, right ?

Comment: Yep and each times the request method is not only get, it has also put and sometimes like this "POST - x-www-form-urlencoded“. What if I use sessions or cookies to store token and then use it in another request? The token's refreshing time is 2hours.

Comment: The only one ways is I need to use the token a lot of time for requesting to API to apply for other function in the app

Comment: What is urlToken ? Is it the token which is  received now ?

Comment: It's the API url that I request to get the token.

Comment: Okay, First time while you are fetching token , you are passing null . Once you have correct token , you have to pass the token in place of null, right ?

Comment: Yes, I need to use the token in other place.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check it now.

Comment: Before each api call, first you have to get the token , and using this token another api will be called. Customize the makeApiCall() function to make dynamic call. I have put few variables to make it dynamic. But you can do it better than me.

Comment: Should I update my interface? because I've got an error on the onDataReceived().

Comment: Yes.     interface TokenCallback {
        void onTokenReceived(String token);
        void onDataReceived(String responseData);
    }

Comment: Thank you, I will come back to you later for any error. Thank you so much!